# How do I format a list of dates from an array of unix timestamps?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, timestamp, unix-timestamp

A WordPress plugin that I'm using is outputting an array (which should be only two dates/times) that looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 1412037900 [1] => 1413340200 [2] => )
```

I'm not sure why there's a trailing empty node but in any case, I'm trying to get a list of the formatted dates/times from this.

I have this in my php (the get_post_meta function is returning the array):

```
<?php global $post;
$date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb2_date_time', true );
foreach ( $date as $item ) {
echo '<p>' . date("F j, Y, g:i a", (int)$item) . '</p>';
} ?>
```

Right now I'm getting this:

```
September 30, 2014, 12:45 am
October 15, 2014, 2:30 am
January 1, 1970, 12:00 am
```

And what I want is this:

```
September 30, 2014, 12:45 am
October 15, 2014, 2:30 am
```

Eventually I'd also like to make it conditional so that it echoes "TBA" when there are no dates.  I can worry about that later once it's working but at the moment when the array is empty I get an error that says "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()..."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just use an if else, if not empty, use foreach, else echo TBA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last result is the datetime equivelant of 0 unix time, as you have an empty object at the end of the array. Simply remove (pop) the last object before converting like this:

```
<?php global $post;
$date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb2_date_time', true );
array_pop($date);
foreach ( $date as $item ) {
echo '<p>' . date("F j, Y, g:i a", (int)$item) . '</p>';
} ?>
```

Then, to include the TBA functionality:

```
<?php global $post;
$date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cmb2_date_time', true );
//If you are still getting an extra object even when there are no dates to be passed 
//from get_post_meta then pop before the check if empty
array_pop($date);
if( empty( $date ) )
{
     echo '<p>TBA</p>';
}
else
{
    //If you are not getting the extra object when empty, only when there are results
    //then put the pop here before the foreach loop
    foreach ( $date as $item ) {
        echo '<p>' . date("F j, Y, g:i a", (int)$item) . '</p>';
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: array_pop returns the last value of the array. Just use array_pop($date), don't assign a variable to it.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks guys!! I did need to move the pop to the foreach side but after that it's doing exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

`date()` will output the current date and time if the final parameter is blank (or the unix epoch if 0), therefore use this code;

```
foreach ( $date as $item ) {
    if($item) echo '<p>' . date("F j, Y, g:i a", (int)$item) . '</p>';
}
```

If the array entry is blank, no date will be echoed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, worldofjr! This one worked perfectly with the full array but it still gave me the "invalid" foreach error when the array was empty.

Comment: You can combat that by declaring an empty array before populating it (or not populating it as the case may be). ie `$date = array();`. This is good practice anyway if you're getting data from another source. Remember to choose the best answer by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the foreach to

```
foreach ( $date as $item ) {
    echo '<p>'.(empty($item)?"TBA":date("F j, Y, g:i a", (int)$item)).'</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, kums, but this one output the two dates and then TBA at the end of the list in place of the unix date.